# How to install nanozip in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I need to decompress an archive and I need this application. How do I install it?

Comment: Why do you need exactly **that** application?

Comment: I am new to the Linux world. Thanks for your reply. In the end nanozip must be extracted in the folder of the archive to be decompressed. Then you go cd to the archive to be decompressed and then in the terminal you add ./nz x archive.nz That's it. In the future i will try to see if other equivalents are compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Go to a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter the following code to install zip and unzip

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unzip zip
```

Now you can unzip the file my going to the directory and typing `unzip <FileNameHere>`

If you want to stick to GUI apps for unzipping, install the following. That way, you just find the file in the file manager, double click it and you can unzip it.

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

Comment: I am still to find out if the 7z format is compatible with the nz one. At the moment I use nanozip to decompress an archive of 4 gb that after decompression will get to over 10 gb. It works very slow. I just got to 2gb in hours.